# Can't populate TableView with plist

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, plist, xcode4.2

I would like to make something like "Add to favorites" technology. In my app there is a `tabbar`. On the first tab there is a form with a button. And what I want to do is when you press the button, it saves the name of navigation bar in the array and saves array in the `plist`. And when you open second tab, you see a view with `tableview` in it, and I would like to see the name of `navigationBar` here, in a cell (so an array takes information from `plist` and puts it in a `tableView`). So here is my code:

```
// Info.h Its a class with button
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class Favorites;
@interface Info : UIViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *favGifts;
    NSString *justAstring;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *favGifts;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *justAstring;

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;
-(NSString *)pathOfFile;

@end

//Info.m

#import "Info.h"

@implementation Info

@synthesize ADFbutton;
@synthesize justAstring;
@synthesize favGifts;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
- (NSString *)pathOfFile {

    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentFolder = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentFolder stringByAppendingFormat:@"myFile.plist"];

}
- (IBAction)save:(id)sende{

    NSString *m = self.navigationItem.title;
    favGifts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [favGifts addObject:m];
    [favGifts writeToFile:[self pathOfFile] atomically:YES];
    justAstring = self.pathOfFile;
    NSLog(@"%@", justAstring);
}

//And this is class with the tableview inside:

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class Info;
@interface Favorites : UIViewController 
<UITableViewDataSource>{

    UITableView *myTableView;
    NSString *name;
    Info *info;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Info *info;

@end
// .m
#import "Favorites.h"
#import "Info.h"

NSMutableArray *array;

@implementation NewFavGifts

@synthesize myTableView;
@synthesize giftInfo;
@synthesize name;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    NSString *filePath = info.justAstring;

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:@"myFile.plist"]) {
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

   }

    [myTableView reloadData];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setMyTableView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue; 
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 75; 
}
@end
```

Xcode doesn't show any errors, but my `tableView` is empty when I open it. 
I can't find my mistake or any solution for 4 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to trouble shoot step by step

Check whether you get any thing in the array by adding NSLog as shown below,

If your getting "Array Count 0" in the console it means nothing is written in the plist file

or if you are not at all getting the NSLog text in the console it means there is no plist file exists

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    NSString *filePath = info.justAstring;

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:@"myFile.plist"]) {
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

   NSLog(@"Array Count %d", [array count)); //add this line and check whether you get any thing in the array
   }

    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for anwser! Console shows 0. BUT, while testing app on the simulator, I went to the \Library\Application Support\iphone simulator\5.0\programm and find out that it writes the string (name of navBar) in the plist every time I press the button.

Comment: Can you post the content of plist file

Comment: Well, I dont know how, but it looks like this:

Key Item 0           Type String             Value Globe

Comment: Try this array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"plist"]];

Comment: Wow, we have a progress!
So, I changed my code to this:
https://gist.github.com/1497522
And it works! But here is one more question:
As I said, I have a form with button and when you press the button, it saves the name of navigationBar, right ? But if you want to go to that form with button, you should tap a cell on the another tableView before. And this tableView has other objects as well. And when I press the button, plist saves all the objects from the tableView and when I move to favorites tab, tableView takes all the objects from the first tableView

Answer (score 1):

There are several things I'd change:

- in the interface definition, add UITableviewDelegate

  @interface Favorites : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate> {
- put your `NSArray *array` into the interface, add a property `nonatomic,retain`
- fill the array with `self.array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:...]`. It doesn't need to be NSMutableArray, but use `self.array` to have it retained properly.